# Create Dynamic DateTimeAxis in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, charts

I have a chart with X-axis showing timeline and Y-axis showing value for an object. The time line values are in 'milliseconds'. I have give the user a way to select timeline, user can select a day/week/month/months. So, in my Chart I want to show all the data points for the selected range but want to limit the date labels displayed on the X-axis. For Ex: if user selects a week, I want to display Mon to Sun on the X-axis. And if user selects a day, want to display a label for every 3 hrs like that...

I guess it is possible if only, I look at the selected time range at run-time and based on the starting (t1) and end (t2) time, I make a decision. Is there any API available in Flex's DateTimeAxis to achieve this ? Or any other ideas on how to get this working ?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a lot of difficulty trying to bend the DateTimeAxis to my will :-P

What I have found works more often for specialized situations like this is to `extend` the `CategoryAxis`.  You can always generate an array of only the dates that you care about and use those as the category axis. I am not sure if this will work for your situation, but it is the first place I would look.

This will of course require a lot more effort, because you need to customize the display of the axis items to look like dates or times, but I think it works for custom situations.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Here I found a solutions for the problem. Similar to what @fotomut mentioned above. I have copied all the code from 'CategoryAxis' except rewrote the 'udpate()' method. This is where the labels get generated. Here is my implementation of update method, may not be a perfect solution....

But, I am facing an issue here. For some reason, the graph and labels looks a bit shifted towards the right hand side. I am unable to post a picture comparing my CustomDateAxis to flex provided CategoryAxis to better explain this, as I am restricted not to upload any files. I am trying to fix this, yet to find a solution...

```
if (!_labelSet)
{

    //I do not need label for each item in my dataprovider.
    //Hence creating a 'categoryValues' array with limited labels.
    var chartDP:ArrayCollection = this.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
    var axisLabels:Array /* of AxisLabel */ = [];
    var labelsArr:Array = [];
    var categoryItems:Array = [];
    var dataMap:Object = {};
    _catMap = {};
    _categoryValues = [];
    _labelsMatchToCategoryValuesByIndex = [];

    if(chartDP.length != 0) {

        for(var indx:int=0; indx<chartDP.length; indx++){

            // Add each item to the map.
            //This is mandatory as it's being used internally to draw the Y-value
            _catMap[chartDP.getItemAt(indx).timeStamp.toString()] = indx;
        }

        var firstItem:Object = chartDP.getItemAt(0);
        var lastItem:Object = chartDP.getItemAt(chartDP.length - 1);
        var incrCounter:int; 

        var timeDiffInMillis:Number = (lastItem.timeStamp) - (firstItem.timeStamp);
        var arrIndx:int=0;
        if(timeDiffInMillis <= MILLISECONDS_IN_HOUR){
            LIMIT_LABEL_CNT = 12;
            INT_LBL_UNITS = "MINUTES";
        }else if(timeDiffInMillis > MILLISECONDS_IN_HOUR && timeDiffInMillis <= MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY){
            LIMIT_LABEL_CNT = 12;
            INT_LBL_UNITS = "HOURS";
        }else if(timeDiffInMillis > MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY && timeDiffInMillis <= MILLISECONDS_IN_WEEK){
            LIMIT_LABEL_CNT = 7;
            INT_LBL_UNITS = "DAYS";
        }else if(timeDiffInMillis > MILLISECONDS_IN_WEEK && timeDiffInMillis <= MILLISECONDS_IN_MONTH){
            LIMIT_LABEL_CNT = 4;
            INT_LBL_UNITS = "WEEKS";
        }else if(timeDiffInMillis > MILLISECONDS_IN_MONTH && timeDiffInMillis <= MILLISECONDS_IN_YEAR) {
            LIMIT_LABEL_CNT = 12;
            INT_LBL_UNITS = "MONTHS"
        }

        if(chartDP.length <= LIMIT_LABEL_CNT)
            incrCounter = 1;
        else
            incrCounter = chartDP.length/LIMIT_LABEL_CNT;
        var i:int=0;
        for(i=0,arrIndx=0; i<chartDP.length; i=i+incrCounter){

            arrIndx = i;
            _categoryValues[arrIndx] = chartDP.getItemAt(i).timeStamp; 
            dataMap[arrIndx] = chartDP.getItemAt(i);

            //There is a very good chance for the incrCounter to omit
            //the last items in the DataProvider.
            if((chartDP.length-i) <= incrCounter){
                arrIndx=arrIndx+incrCounter;
                _categoryValues[arrIndx] = chartDP.getItemAt(chartDP.length-1).timeStamp; 
                dataMap[arrIndx] = chartDP.getItemAt(chartDP.length-1);
            }
        }

        var min:Number = -_padding;
        var max:Number = _categoryValues.length - 1 + _padding;
        var alen:Number = max - min;
        var label:AxisLabel;

        var n:int = _categoryValues.length;
        if (_labelFunction != null)
        {
            var previousValue:Object = null;
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                if (_categoryValues[i] == null)
                    continue;

                if(previousValue != null && _categoryValues[i] != null){
                    if(previousValue == _categoryValues[i])
                        continue;
                }
                label = new AxisLabel((i - min) / alen, _categoryValues[i],
                    timeLblFormatFunction(_categoryValues[i], previousValue,
                        this, dataMap[i]));
                _labelsMatchToCategoryValuesByIndex[i] = label;
                axisLabels.push(label);

                previousValue = _categoryValues[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (!_categoryValues[i])
                    continue;

                label = new AxisLabel((i - min) / alen, _categoryValues[i],
                    _categoryValues[i].toString());
                _labelsMatchToCategoryValuesByIndex[i] = label;
                axisLabels.push(label);
            }               
        }
    }

    _labelSet = new AxisLabelSet();
    _labelSet.labels = axisLabels;
    _labelSet.accurate = true;
    _labelSet.minorTicks = minorTicks;
    _labelSet.ticks = generateTicks();          
}
```

Comment: Okay, found the answer to the issue where the labels are being shifted to the right. The '_padding' property was doing the trick. I found from the class documentation that the 'padding' value gets reset to '0' for linecharts/areachart and 0.5 to columnchart/barchart. But this was not happening to me in case of linechart for some reason, hence I am forcing it to '0' to do it. Now, my chart works as expected with generic X-axis. Thanks....